# WIX: RemoveExistingProducts on upgrade when failed to start services (uninstall completely)

Tags: c#, wix, failed-installation, major-upgrade

I have a use-case wherein user clicks Cancel after starting the services while upgrade. Our repository upgrade code is in windows service(written in C#), its not capable of downgrading. So since the service upgrades the repo, user clicks cancel upgrade, wix rollsback and installs old service back in place and tries to start the service(old). Since the repo is already upgraded, service can't be started.
In this case, we need to trigger uninstall of the product. I see that **MajorUpgrade's Schedule** property provides five different options

- afterInstallValidate,
- afterInstallInitialize,
- afterInstallExecute,
- afterInstallExecuteAgain,
- afterInstallFinalize.

But none serves the purpose. Basically I need something like "**beforeStartServices**".

Does anyone have any idea?